# C# inheritance virtual or override

Tags: c#

I have three classes.

Person -> Employee -> Manager

Person has a virtual method declared as

```
public virtual void saySomething()
```

Inside of Employee I have

```
public virtual void saySomething()
```

OR

```
public override void saySomething()
```

And I get the same behavior

Inside of Manager I have

```
public override void saySomething()
```

I'm confused with the fact that I can use override in replace of virtual? I thought you use override to signify the fact that this class has overridden one of the base class function.

How do I stop a method from being overriden? This is the last method.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Adding `public virtual void saySomething()` in the subclass is *re-declaring* the method (method-hiding; you probably get a warning about that).

It will behave the same if you access it as:

```
Employee emp = ...
emp.saySomething();
```

but now add:

```
Person per = emp;
per.saySomething();
```

With *polymorphism* (via `override`) they should do the same thing. But via method-hiding they won't. To *explicitly* hide a method, use `new`:

```
new public virtual void saySomething() {...}
```

or to *stop* something being overridden any further, use `sealed`:

```
public sealed override void saySomething() {...}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `sealed` keyword to stop a virtual being overridden any further in your inheritance hierarchy.

Your use of override is correct in `Employee`, you want to **override** the default implementation provided by `Person`. `virtual` in the `Employee` type for the `saySomething` method is incorrect.

Answer (score 1):

You have to use [sealed](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa645769%28v=vs.71%29.aspx) key word.